# SQLite в нескольких одновременных подключения INSERT / UPDATE

Tags: c++, sqlite3

Можно ли выполнять INSERT / UPDATE из разных программ, одновременно подключенных к одном файлу базы данных SQLite? Если можно то как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

[Об этом можно прочесть в документации](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html).

Если коротко, то - **можно**. Согласно документации:

1)

> SQLite Version 3.0.0 introduced a new locking and journaling mechanism designed to improve concurrency over SQLite version 2 and to reduce the writer starvation problem. The new mechanism also allows atomic commits of transactions involving multiple database files.

2)

> SQLite uses POSIX advisory locks to implement locking on Unix. On Windows it uses the LockFile(), LockFileEx(), and UnlockFile() system calls.

3)

> SQLite uses filesystem locks to make sure that only one process and database connection is trying to modify the database at a time. The filesystem locking mechanism is implemented in the VFS layer and is different for every operating system. SQLite depends on this implementation being correct. If something goes wrong and two or more processes are able to write the same database file at the same time, severe damage can result.

Кто может помочь с корректным переводом на русскй - прошу исправить мое сообщение. К сожалению, я только бегло читаю.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/143684)

Comment: Из документации достал нужную инфу и процитировал. За перевод не взялся, мой английский только на уровне беглого чтения.

Comment: Кстати ... мой ответ практически дубль отсюда http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373409/concurrent-access-in-sqlite